# Screen flashing black randomly, on desktop and applications Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, flash

I've tried looking for a way to provide what's happening but its so random it's hard to recreate. What's happening is both monitors will flash  black but only the top half of the screens and not at the same time, the closest thing i can describe this as is when a program opens and the terminal flashes for a split second then closes. But nothing is opening, it appears to be something wrong with an nvidia driver maybe? Anyone else having this issue? It's been happening for about a week.
Nvidia driver 535 / GTX 1660 Super

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, I found a fix I downgraded the driver from 535 to 525 and all is working properly. So if anyone else runs into this issue swap to 525.